# docker-compose postgres fatal role and db does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

When I run my docker-compose file, it builds two images, an api and a postgres image. The postgres image is getting a couple of different errors depending on what I do. If my `POSTGRES_USER` is set as `myUser`, I get `FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`, and if I change the value of that var to `root`, I get `FATAL:  database "root" does not exist`.

I don't know why it's looking for `root` as both the role/user and as the db. I would like to use my own values for those, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm running a pretty basic postgres Dockerfile (Dockerfile.db):

```
ENV POSTGRES_USER myUser
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD myPassword
ENV POSTGRES_DB myDb
COPY db_template.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and the docker-compose file looks like this:

```
services:
  api-template:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=dbtemplate
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=myUser
      - POSTGRES_DB=myDb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: api-template
    depends_on:
      dbtemplate:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks: 
      - shared-net

  dbtemplate:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=dbtemplate
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=myUser
      - POSTGRES_DB=myDb
    container_name: dbtemplate
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks: 
      - shared-net

networks:
  shared-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Look at this: `/docker-entrypoint=initdb.d/`. Is that a typo? The equals should be a hyphen.

Comment: Thank you, good eye. That has resolved some issues, but I am still getting the FATAL: role "root" does not exist

Comment: (I updated the original question to reflect the typo fix)